# XSL and XSLT Javascript Working in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a HTML file which Uses XSL and XML. It works perfectly in IE (What a Surprise) but it does not work in Chrome and Firefox. The JavaScript in the code works only in IE. Can anybody help me solving this issue? I have given the JavaScript below

```
<BODY onload="view()" topmargin="10" leftmargin="5" rightmargin="5" bottommargin="10" marginwidth="0">
<div ID="divResults">
</div>
<script language="javascript">
    var xmlDOM, xslDOM;
    function view() {
        xslDOM = XSLStyle.XMLDocument;
        xmlDOM = REPORT.XMLDocument;
        document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML = xmlDOM.transformNode(xslDOM);
    }
    function dsble_Help() {
        return false;
    }
    document.onhelp = dsble_Help
</script>
```

REPORT ID :

```
<XML ID="REPORT">
<REPORT>
    <HD>
        <RPTID>NAE100RX</RPTID>
        <RUNDT>04/29/2013</RUNDT>
        <RUNTM>17.24.13</RUNTM>
        <ASOFDT>04/29/2013</ASOFDT>
        <HD1>CREATE TRIGGERS EXCEPTION REPORT</HD1>
        <HD2>FOR 04/29/2013</HD2>
        <HD3></HD3>
    </HD> 
    <XPAGE>
        <RPAGE>1</RPAGE>
        <AE100XCNT>0</AE100XCNT>
        <EXDATA></EXDATA>
    </XPAGE>
</REPORT>
```

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console? What are `XSLStyle.XMLDocument` and `REPORT.XMLDocument`? Where do they come from?

Comment: Can you please add in what way it fails?

Comment: REPORT and XSLStyle are the Corresponding XML and XSL embedded in HTML

Answer (score 4):

From your XML example, you seem to be using an IE only feature - [XML data islands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This cannot be made to work with other browsers.

You will need to use [standardized techniques](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) in order to do so in the other browsers.

Comment: Oded, I was able to follow your link and was able to create XMLDcoument but still XML and XSL are not converted to HTML. Here is code I used, var p = new DOMParser()
var xmldoc = p.parseFromString(document.getElementById("REPORT").innerHTML, 'text/xml')
var xsldoc = p.parseFromString(document.getElementById("XSLStyle").innerHTML, 'text/xml')
xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsldoc);
resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmldoc, document);
document.getElementById("htmlBody").appendChild(resultDocument);

Comment: @user2367884 - Any JavaScript errors in the console? Do you see values in `xmldoc` and `xsldoc` when debugging through?